# error: slick.model.Table does not take type parameters

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am migrating from slick-extenstions to slick 3.2.0

```
import slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, Tag}
import slick.model.Table


class Admin(tag : Tag) extends Table[(Long, Long)](tag, "NT_CV_ADMIN_SHORT") {
  def parentId = column[Long]("PARENT_ID")
  def maxAdminShort = column[Long]("MAX_ADMIN_SHORT")

  override def * : ProvenShape[(Long, Long)] = (parentId, maxAdminShort)
}
```

For the above declaration of table I am getting following error -
*error: slick.model.Table does not take type parameters*

Here is the dependency I used -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
            <artifactId>slick_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't understand what I am missing. I saw slick3.2.0 manual - https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/gettingstarted.html, that's how I have created the table.
I don't know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported the wrong `Table`.

Slick is kinda confusing in that it wants you to get most of your imports from a "driver" class. The getting started guide you linked tells you to add these imports:

```scala
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

If you were using a different database e.g. MySQL you would `import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._` instead.

Here are the scaladocs for the `api` type: https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile$API - as you can see from that page, the `api` provides a whole bunch of type aliases and values. The `Table` you want is the one in there.